# how to get number of rows from Struts JSP table using javascript

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp, struts2

I have table in JSP struts, that get's generated dynamically. I would to use javascript to get the number of rows the table has generated. Here's a sample code

```
<s:iterator status="state" id="myTable">
<td><s:textfield name="username" id="username" cssClass="size40" readonly="true" tabindex="-1" /></td>
 <td><s:textfield name="lastName" id="lastName" cssClass="size40" readonly="true" tabindex="-1" /></td>
</tr>
                    </s:iterator>
```

I tried using this code

```
 var x = document.getElementById("myTable").rows.length;
alert(x);
```

but it doesn't return anything

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle or post the generated HTML?

Comment: How is your table is generated? (There isn't any table in your code and seems like your iterator tag doesn't do anything.) Do you want to simple display number of rows or do you really need this number in javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, `id="myTable"` is not an `id` of a DOM object which could then be retrieved through JavaScript. It's a *Struts 2 identifier* referring to a collection available on the *ValueStack*. In fact, to cut the confusion the latest *Struts 2* versions now use the attribute `var` in place of the `id`.

I would suggest to simply initialize your JavaScript variable to your collection's `size` via Struts instead of processing the resulting HTML table.

```
var x = <s:property value="myTable.size" />;
alert(x);
```

It's much simpler this way.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can get the count of table rows in iterative table

```
  <%
    int count=0;
    %> <s:iterator status="state" id="myTable">
           <% count ++; %>
        <td><s:textfield name="username" id="username" cssClass="size40" readonly="true" tabindex="-1" /></td>
         <td><s:textfield name="lastName" id="lastName" cssClass="size40" readonly="true" tabindex="-1" /></td>
        </tr>
                        </s:iterator>
<input type="text" id="tableCount" style="display:none;" value="<%= count%>">
```

In javascript

```
var x = document.getElementById("tableCount").value;
alert(x);
```

Comment: I think use of `<% Scriptlets %>` has been long deprecated. I wouldn't recommend using them specially when OP is going all out to use MVC with Struts!

Comment: Point noted.. Thank you :)